# How to turn off on-console job log/dump while executing SQL query in HIVE?

Tags: sql, linux, hadoop, hive

While executing SQL query in hive using command line it generated on-screen text/log/dump on progress of ongoing job which included Number of mapper/reducre, current job details and percentage of mapper/reduceer job finished. I want to switch off this log and just print the resulyt on console. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can suppress these messages using -S option. Seeing this option hear the reject of showing only the output result of the queries.
Example:
%hive -S select * from mytable